# Inclusion project - Emphasize Stack Exchange's culture of inclusion

Tags: discussion, etiquette, inclusion-project

One of the more common defenses I've seen for rude/discriminating behavior is justifying it with multiculturalism.

I know that sounds odd on its face, so let me explain...

Users seem to be justifying behaving badly by claiming that it's the norm in their neck of the woods. Sometimes that's even accurate, but I suspect, more often than not, it's just a lame excuse.

Admittedly, some places seem to be ok with some kinds of discrimination, it's a sad fact of the world.  Some places have made a little more progress, and while that's great, they're still fighting to make it a little better... Stack Exchange seems to have become one of the latter places.

I'd prefer that Stack Exchange communities put their own culture first. As in:

> We don't care where you come from, you still have to treat people like people here.

That seems to be a corner stone of the Be Nice policy, at least as far as my reading of it. Although this can apparently be interpreted more than one way.

To flatly come out and say:

> It's not ok to treat X that way.

Can be considered rude in some cultures, if you're going by the standard set by a given culture. How they feel about how X should be treated is culturally ingrained, often backed by eons of tradition, religion, and so on. This obviously creates a big stumbling block...

What I would like to suggest is plainly saying that Stack Exchange is a community with its own culture, and the norms and rules of our culture come first.

We don't want to offend users from any part of the world, from any religion, or culture, but when it comes to some things... Well...  That's just how we do it here. This is what ***our*** community feels is ***right***.

Thoughts?

Comment: On matters of etiquette ("thanks" and the like), I might agree. But there can be other areas where the culture of SO needs to bend to the culture of the real world.

Comment: @NicolBolas What might those areas be?

Comment: I donno, "It's not ok to treat X that way." is *literally* a cornerstone of my moderation style. And what's wrong with folks working out what to do with common sense? And could we have some specific examples please since... its not quite clear what the goal here is, and the eventual end result.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I didn't intend to say that folks weren't making an effort, but very clearly there's some problems on the table. Today's blog post seemed to try to highlight that.

Comment: More that sites can work out what needs to be done, with a bit of broader guidance, rather than a strict, universal code of "how we do things". I for one would take sexism on SU quite dimly.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's kinda my point... When users want to say "That's how we treat women where I live" I think the appropriate response should be, "well, that's not how we treat women on SE"

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Put another way, sometimes [Lower Elbonians](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269289/our-words-are-too-complicated-lets-make-them-simpler/269320#269320) really just need to learn to adjust to SE culture, rather than primarily the other way around. Put even more bluntly, "Elbonians" can have cultural values, or at least habits, that *we don't like*, and don't plan on *ever* liking or tolerating. That's OK. (SE can still make a good effort to *understand Elbonians* in order to handle their culture shock and help them adjust as much as possible, of course.)

Comment: But do we need a rule to stop them from filling our living room with mud explicitly?

Comment: @Journeyman some examples: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309538/217863

Comment: @apaul none of them from SO:)

Comment: ["That's true. What may be implicit bias in SO becomes explicit on some other sites on the network. Subjects like racism, sexism, homophobia, xenophobia, etc aren't on topic on SO, but they are on some other sites. When questions dealing with these subjects hit HNQ, things get pretty awful pretty quickly."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309513/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-especially-marginalized-groups#comment1009399_309538) @MartinJames

Comment: @MartinJames Also... I don't believe I referenced Stack Overflow at any point in my question. Feel free to correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 15):

Hmmm...

> I'd prefer that Stack Exchange communities put their own culture first.

We already do this. In fact, it's *probably* the root of an awful lot of the complaints that we get, since the shared Stack Exchange culture is *significantly different* from the predominate cultural norms of the 'Net, and even moreso when you take certain Eastern cultural norms into account.

And... Even though we kinda know that an awful lot of folks showing up here suffer from culture shock, we're often not that great at acclimating them to it. Seasoned member unutbu [wrote about this recently over on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions/366394#366394):

> My early confusion came from a conflict in cultures perhaps not dissimilar to they one some new-flowers face when asking questions to us overflowers. But I believe we tend to learn to adapt to the culture that we are in. So let's try to welcome / acculturate new-flowers by trying to be respectful and patient while showing by example how people are expected to behave on Stack Overflow.

Truth is, we're often very brusque about how we introduce these norms to new members of these sites; we may even betray our frustration with seeing so many of them by going out of our way to chastise others for their transgressions.

Should we abandon our culture then? Certainly not! Doing so hardly solves the problem of culture-clash, nor is it in any way practical to even attempt it. But we would do well to remember [the reasons behind our little rituals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362473/how-do-i-respond-to-assertions-that-stack-overflow-is-just-like-a-forum/362474#3624740), so that we can better explain them to others - and reminding ourselves that [the fixtures which we take for granted can look very strange and confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240440/what-is-a-meta-for) until folks become accustom to them.

We also need to remember that Stack Exchange has grown considerably over its life - not just in size, but in breadth of both topic and diversity of culture. Participating on TeX is not the same as participating on Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair and neither are anything like participating on Worldbuilding; while all these sites share many common attributes, their individual cultures also have much that is unique or at least uncommon - [cultural exports work by persuasion, not edict](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/individual-community-preferences-vs-se-network-policy-who-wins). This isn't done in the name of "multiculturalism", but of practical necessity: what works for one topic or group may destroy another; if we're to host these diverse topics on our platform, then the folks involved must be free to adapt to what allows that to happen effectively.

Over the years, I've had to explain again and again to people whose culture dictates that they *must* upvote their superiors' posts that such behavior is forbidden here; numerous others have faced this same task. It would certainly be *less work* to just abandon our own goals and expectations in the face of such pressure - but the cost of doing so is the slow destruction of much of what we've built here.

So we patiently provide the same guidance again and again, day after day, year after year, to each new member who makes the same mistake. And they learn, and they adapt, and we are all better for it.

Comment: I was more trying to address the issues raised by folks who tend to think that other folks shouldn't be treated with basic human decency. As in "it's just fine to treat women like property in my country, you're forcing your cultural beliefs on others when you tell people that that's not ok..."

Comment: Again, I feel like this is already covered - it's never been OK to treat women like property on Stack Exchange, and I've personally banned multiple people who've tried. I suspect there's some missing context here.

Comment: An example: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/75643/2018/4/7 (may want to delete this comment to avoid naming and shaming)

Comment: Ok, I scanned the thread there @apaul - I'm not sure what sparked it, but am I correct in summarizing it as "you and another user disagreed over the probable meaning of women's attire in public situations in Thailand"? I'm really not wild about some of the language in that thread, though I can't tell at a glance if it's the other user being crude or if that somehow ties back to a question on IPS.

Comment: Here's the thread that started it: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/how-can-i-avoid-the-awkwardness-of-a-returning-player-who-wears-a-low-cut-shirt

Comment: And the subsequent meta post that made it a little more glaring: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/how-to-talk-about-who-is-responsible-who-is-to-blame

Comment: Ok. So, there's nothing in there about Thailand, Germany, or any other local culture that I can find - which makes most of that chat conversation a non sequitur at best; I've deleted it. The main-site question was about communication, which does not in any way warrant a debate over womens' dressing proclivities outside of the specific context defined there; the meta question was about someone feeling they have a right to kibitz on the main-site topic, which they do not. Thankfully, *none* of it was about how women should be treated on Stack Exchange, which is what I had feared.

Comment: However... Much as we might wish otherwise, nothing we decide here is going to have much of an effect on the cultural norms in Thailand apart from perhaps influencing one particular German guy's interpretation of them. So I'm still unclear where you were going with this request.

Comment: Ah... That's where we're drawing the line... It's ok to promote a pretty awful line of thought about how people should be treated, provided that they're not exactly demonstrating that behavior on the network. Hmm.

Comment: I don't see how anything I said would give that impression. This is not a soapbox for folks to promote such things, which is why all of that user's comments to that effect (at least, the ones outside of your chat room) were deleted... two weeks ago.

Comment: That's one of many users, who've used a pretty lame "this is how it works where I come from" excuse. Or my personal favorite "this is how it works in the real world". Figured it was worth driving the point that it isn't how it works on SE, because it comes up often enough.

Comment: Actually... I'm becoming increasingly curious about the chronology here. Presumably you saw this guy spewing this crap on the post, and saw the mods clean it up. Then you saw the meta post and *more* cleanup. And... Three days later, you invite him to a chat room to spew *more* of it, and don't clean it up? What the hell, man?

Comment: So yeah, here's how SE's culture applies to this situation: don't do that. Don't give people a damn soapbox for that crap. And if they try to do it anyway, flag it instead of encouraging it.

Comment: Nah, the chat was an honest attempt to get through to him. Perhaps misguided, but that was the intent. Hoped that trying to talk it out, one on one, would get him to reevaluate what he'd been thinking and saying. I find that some people don't say the crappy thing when they have the time to really think about it.

Comment: Well, I can't deny that's a noble effort. But probably could've cut that short at the first "asking for it" response.

Comment: Probably right about that. Part of why I've stepped away from IPS till these things find better solutions.

Comment: Out of curiosity... And my general angsty pot stirring nature... Why isn't it an option to make a more direct statement that bigots aren't welcome? I know that's harsh, but it seems like we're approaching a point where it may he needed.  Assuming good intentions is good, as far as it goes, but why not simply say "if you honestly believe that some folks don't deserve basic human rights, this isn't the network for you"?

Comment: A very old cultural tradition on Stack Exchange is to focus on behaviors vs. labeling, @apaul. We don't vote on who has to wear the label "bigot" (or "troll", or "vampire", or...) - we dictate acceptable behavior: [no bigotry](/help/be-nice). Also, that's sort of a definition that mostly just makes the definer feel good.

Comment: Ya... But the behavior has been going on for a good little while now... So...  Why not be more direct?

Comment: What would it accomplish, beyond fodder for more arguments? If you say, "don't do that" and they do it anyway, standing around discussing which label to apply is a waste of time; shut it down. This is what kills so much time on IPS: folks will point out a problem and then stand around for the next 6 hours saying "nuh-uh! uh-huh!" at each other as though that resolves anything. Either the problem exists or it doesn't; calling the author names isn't fixing the problem.

Comment: Perhaps better put "If you don't believe that some folks deserve basic human rights, this isn't the network for you." The blog post seemed to be inching toward that, but didn't seem to want to say it.

Comment: We can skip the label. Just come out and say it, and say it directly. Some folks seem to believe that those perspectives are ok on the network, making a direct statement that they're not could make a difference.

Comment: We have a direct statement. I linked to it above. The blog post references it.

Comment: How well has that been working? Has it led to users thinking that they shouldn't post the awful? Has it been as effective as anyone had hoped? Or has it led people to think that if they stay on "just this side of polite discourse" they can say whatever they want? Take a hard look. You know it's happening. You know you can do something about it.

Comment: If I've completely lost my mind here, what was the point of the blog post? I thought you all had a moment of clarity on this stuff?

Comment: I honestly don't know what you're looking for here, @apaul.

Comment: A public service announcement, much like the blog post, but well... More direct, and more honest. "If you're the sort of person who believes that some folks don't deserve basic human rights, then this isn't the network for you"

Comment: You seem to be saying that that's how "be nice" should be interpreted. So say that, publicly, and often.

Comment: How is that in any way more direct than what we have *now*?

Comment: It leaves a little less room for interpretation...

Comment: Also helps when it isn't just a link to a page that most folks don't really read. Say it when you delete comments. Say it when you delete answers, and questions.

Comment: It leaves TONS of room for interpretation. Any time you stop looking at what folks are writing and try to put them into boxes based on what you think they believe, you're in the weeds as far as getting any kind of consensus. You're defining a problem based on who you think you've been arguing with rather than what they said... But I gotta tell you: even the blatant, over the top *literally cartoon* Nazis we've been blocking for months across the network don't sign up with "Occupation: antisemite" filled in on their profiles.

Comment: Obviously you can snark with the best of them. You've been doing this for a long time, and as much as it doesn't look that way at the moment, I respect that. A personal message from someone like you can have more impact than the typical "be nice" link. You lot, the SE rockstars carry a certain amount of weight. When you take a stand against the sort of nonsense I've been seeing, people will probably listen.

Comment: I appreciate the flattery, but... Most folks using these sites don't know me from Adam. And giving someone who is spewing hate a soapbox for the sake of being able to publicly condemn them, while certainly cathartic... Still gives a soapbox to someone spewing hatred. It isn't worth the price.

Comment: And that's why I stepped down... I'm too close to the issue, and I'm too hot tempered. You on the other hand seem to be very good at this. And like it, or not, you're a role model on the network. People follow your lead. You have the ability to do something meaningful here in a way that most folks don't.

Comment: How far I can reach with my words is debatable. But there is one scenario where I've learned that a public condemnation is valuable, albeit one that is extremely hard to pull off: when a certain behavior is so pervasive, so controversial that it cannot readily be shut down... When an author has managed to craft for themselves a nearly bulletproof figleaf for their words... Then addressing it head on for the sake of those who suffer is worthwhile. But, in my experience, it does *nothing* to stall the author themselves, and there is nearly always collateral damage.

Comment: Hmm... Seems like a comp out. But then again, you're the expert...

Comment: Heh... If you haven't noticed, I *love* to argue. If I could justify it from the results, that'd be all I'd do here. But I can't. The more pitched battles you fight, the fewer people remain save those who just want to fight.

Comment: Also wasn't really talking about a public condemnation.  More of a **"If you don't believe that some folks deserve basic human rights, this isn't the network for you."** users can then decide if that's what they really believe. It's a choice, not a condemnation.

Comment: Really beginning to look an awful lot like the blog post was just more piss in the wind. I guess we're going to continue doing what we've been doing while pretending that that works...

Comment: Meanwhile: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2877/59

Comment: @apaul Please explain, I honestly don't get it, what is the problem with Edgar's answer? How does it follow from it that Edgar thinks that some folks don't deserve basic human rights? Is it the Forest Gump reference? Also I wonder do you think bigots should be treated with basic human decency and deserve basic human rights?

Comment: @Oleg The problem with the answer is that it isn't an answer to the question, and the Forrest Gump thing is somewhat offensive. And last time I checked being denied a platform on a website doesn't qualify as a human rights violation. That's what I've been suggesting, once again from the top "if you believe that some folks don't deserve basic human rights, this isn't the network for you."

Comment: @apaul Thanks for answering, I appreciate it.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309513/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-especially-marginalized-groups/309586#comment1009536_309554

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/does-stack-exchange-really-want-to-conflate-newbies-with-women-people-of-color/366688#comment579538_366688

Comment: Just wanted to give you an opportunity to make a couple of more effective public statements. Or ya'know not.

Comment: @apaul: Not to put too fine a point on this, but I honestly don't care at all what beliefs a person has so long as they are willing to treating others with decency and respect here.  Down the road you propose lies the thought police; down that road lies madness.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Slippery slope is an easy argument to make about anything... What I was trying to get at here was the tendency for people to want to say "all beliefs are equally valid, so we can't take sides" even in cases where people have already crossed the line from beliefs to behavior. There's a big difference between saying that a comment or answer was removed because it's not constructive, or doesn't answer the question, and removing it because it violates the be nice policy. I've been seeing an awful lot of biggotry sliding through because it's on just this side of civil discourse...

Comment: Nobody said that, @apaul. I said, and Robert said again, that we can't police beliefs, and even trying is hugely problematic. We can *and do* police behaviors: words posted and actions taken on these sites. The day we stop censoring abusive actions and start censoring *any* words from people we label as "abusive" is the day this all falls apart.

Comment: Seems like we've been talking past each other... I'm not so much asking that beliefs be policed, but rather expressed beliefs that violate site policy. Once biggotry is expressed on a Stack, it kinda has crossed the line. We don't typically have a problem scolding users for any other negative behavior, but there seems to be some hesitation in scolding them for making bigoted statements.

Comment: I kinda suspect you're suffering from a lack of visibility into that, @apaul. You see what we *don't* delete. And, maybe we should be deleting more - but that's gotta start with someone calling out a problem and others agreeing, we don't do roving gangs of moderators doing what is right in their own eyes and accountable to no one.

Comment: Sure have a thing for hyperbole... I'm basically asking for you all to do the things that you claim to already be doing. Perhaps they tend to get done behind the scenes and it's just not as visible as it could be, or perhaps there's some room for improvement. If I recall, several users who had been consistently problematic caught long term suspensions once they started poking you directly, but even then it took quite a bit of poking before action was taken. These same users had been causing problems and drawing an awful lot of flags for a long time before that.

Comment: And you have a gift for ignoring things you wish weren't true, @apaul. I gave y'all a *roadmap* to follow when one of the users you're referring to first took an interest in IPS. Remember that? You got all defensive because you'd fallen for his cellophane bag of tricks, and spent the next few months actively working against the folks trying to put a stop to the nonsense. So instead of complaining that we're not doing enough, maybe work with us instead of compounding the problem.

Comment: Ya, I wasn't a big fan of the excessively pedantic route. In some ways I still struggle with that. But... If you all knew that there was a problem. You knew that a specific user was trolling. You knew that other users were showing up purely to play politics with the alt-right silliness... Why not just suspend them? Was this some sort of long game lesson for the community?

Comment: Not really a game, @apaul; this is pretty much my job description. I can't moderate every action of every user on every site every day... That's not how this is set up to work; everyone has a role to play. So it doesn't help if I tell you "userNNNN is a troll" - then your only heuristic is "users named 'userNNNN'". If they're being legit on one post, that's a false-positive; if they create a new account and use it to troll, that's a false negative. HORRIBLE heuristic! So how do we deal with trolls? We teach people to recognize trolling, and shut it down.You'd be surprised how often that works.

Comment: Ya... There's some truth in that, but there's also the other part. CMs are often the only ones with the cross site data and ability to impose IP bans. Sure teach us how to spot them, but after they've been spotted don't leave us to deal with them for months there after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1192/discussion-between-shog9-and-apaul).

Comment: This conversation is interesting in today's light.

Answer (score 2):

> One of the more common defenses I've seen for rude/descriminating behavior is justifying it with multiculturalism.

I think there are some issues on Stack Exchange as regards to the "be nice" policy. And I'm not a fan of multiculturism at all - I think it's used to excuse a lot of bad things. So I'm listening.

> I know that sounds odd on its face, so let me explain. Users seem to be justifying behaving badly by claiming that it's the norm in their neck of the woods. Sometimes that's even accurate, but I suspect, more often than not, it's just a lame excuse.

I've seen plenty of users being unpleasant. And not just new users, or users from distant lands with different cultures - I'm in the UK by the way. But I've never seen multiculturalism used as an excuse for unpleasantness on Stack Exchange. Maybe I've led a sheltered life.

> Admittedly, some places seem to be ok with some kinds of discrimination, it's a sad fact of the world. Some places have made a little more progress, and while that's great, they're still fighting to make it a little better... Stack Exchange seems to have become one of the latter places.

A lot of places are OK with some kind of discrimination. Only they sweep it under the rug or call it "affirmative action" or somesuch. But I haven't noticed much in the way of discrimination on Stack Exchange. I've noticed that some longer term users aren't always nice to new users, but I don't think that's discrimination per se.

> I'd prefer that Stack Exchange communities put their own culture first. As in: We don't care where you come from, you still have to treat people like people here.

I agree with that. And I would venture to say that that's the intent. Perhaps the real issue here is [Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F). If people aren't being nice, then surely the moderators need to do something about it? And if they don't, then somebody needs to have a chat with them?

> That seems to be a cornerstone of the be nice policy, at least as far as my reading of it. Although this can apparently be interpreted more than one way. To flatly come out and say *It's not ok to treat X that way* can be considered rude in some cultures, if you're going by the standard set by a given culture. How they feel about how X should be treated is culturally ingrained, often backed by eons of tradition, religion, and so on. This obviously creates a big stumbling block...

There is the saying *When in Rome*. I agree with that. A lot of people do.

> What I would like to suggest is plainly saying that Stack Exchange is a community with its own culture, and the norms and rules of our culture come first.

Who wouldn't agree with that? Provided that culture has that *be nice* ethic of course.

> We don't want to offend users from any part of the world, from any religion, or culture, but when it comes to some things... Well...  That's just how we do it here. This is what ***our*** community feels is ***right***. Thoughts?

I share your sentiment. But the bottom line is that I haven't noticed that this is a problem on Stack Exchange. I guess what I'm saying is that for this one, we really do need some examples. I know that can be problematical, but I see no other option here.